# SQL*Loader - load CSV with multiple chunks

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I've got a CSV file that contains multiple data chunkds:

```
Alice
Age,Weight,Height
20y,50kg,170cm
Bob
Age,Weight,Height
22y,80kg,180cm
```

I need to load it into table PEOPLE in such way:

```
Name   |  Age   |  Weight   |  Height 
Alice     20y       50kg        170cm
Bob       22y       80kg        180cm
```

Is it possible to do it with SQL*Loader? 
Other way is to write a csv pre-processor on groovy for example, but it would be much better to solve it simply with SQl*Loader

Comment: You have Age, Weight, Height and only those three fields for every chunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on linux and or have access to `awk`:

```
awk -v Q="'" -F "," \
    'BEGIN {
         print "create table YOURTABLE (name varchar2(X), age varchar2(Y), weight varchar2(Z), height varchar2(N));"
     }
     /^[^,]\+$/ {name=$0}
     /^Age,Weight,Height$/ {
         getline 
         print "insert into YOURTABLE values (" Q name Q ", " Q $1 Q ", " Q $2 Q ", " Q $3 Q ") ;"
         print "commit;"
     }
     END { print "exit;" }' INPUT.CSV > LOAD.SQL
```

So it prints a `create table ...` statement in which you should replace your field lengths and tabblename. Then reads your CSV and on every line if the line does *not* contain any `,` it sets the `name` variable, then on every `Age,Weight,Height` line reads the next one and prints an `insert` statement with the contents (and a `commit;`). At the end it prints an `exit;`.

At voila, you can load it with `sqlplus`.

Or rewrite it a bit to create a standard `csv`, it's easy.

Comment: +1. with that awk you can just parse de input and make it standard csv in order to load it with SQL.

Comment: You are right @FlorinGhita, why can't that popped into my mind? I need to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to just load it into an intermediate table (or load it as an external table) with generic columns C1, C2, C3; then it'd be simple to write the SQL to process it.